# Issue with Accessing GraphQL Data Before Authentication on Android using Amplify

Tags: android, react-native, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Question:
Hello everyone,

I'm relatively new to Amplify and currently working on a mobile application using React Native. The app is being developed for both Android and iOS platforms. I've integrated Amplify Auth and a GraphQL API into the app. While I'm able to access GraphQL data before authentication on iOS successfully, I'm encountering a peculiar issue on Android where the data retrieval returns an empty array. I'm hoping to get some insights into the cause of this discrepancy and find a solution.

Problem Description:
I'm developing a React Native app that involves utilizing Amplify to interact with an AppSync GraphQL API. One specific requirement is to access GraphQL data even before the user is authenticated. Surprisingly, this functionality is working as expected on iOS, but it's not yielding the same results on Android. On Android, the data retrieval operation results in an empty array.

Request for Assistance:
I'm reaching out to the community to seek guidance on the following points:

Is there anything inherently different about Amplify's behavior or configuration on Android that might lead to this issue?
What possible factors could be causing the discrepancy between iOS and Android?
Are there any specific settings or steps that need to be taken when working with Amplify on Android, especially for accessing unauthenticated GraphQL data?
Things I've Checked:

The GraphQL query itself seems to be correct, as it works on iOS.
Both iOS and Android versions of the app are using the same version of Amplify.
I've ensured that the necessary dependencies are installed for both platforms.
Code Snippet (for Reference):
Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using for data retrieval:

```
import { API, GRAPHQL_AUTH_MODE } from 'aws-amplify';
import * as queries from './src/graphql/queries';

const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await API.graphql({
      query: queries.listItems,
      authMode: GRAPHQL_AUTH_MODE.API_KEY,
    });

    // Process the response
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
  }
};

fetchData();
```

Conclusion:
I greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or troubleshooting steps that the community can provide. This issue has me stuck, and I'm eager to find a resolution. Thank you all in advance for your assistance!

Comment: can you also share schema file?